# Resharper wants me to implement an interface member that is implemented in WPF generated code

Tags: c#, wpf, resharper

Simple class:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

`class MainWindow` is underlined red, resharper is complaining that `IComponentConnector.Connect is not implemented`. Checking the file `obj\Debug\MainWindow.g.i.cs` the method is there, and the compiler does not complain about anything.

What am I missing? Is this a bug in R#? I've got so many false solution errors at the moment - this count is useless.

### Update

Problem persists even after:

1. removing all _ReSharper files
2. a fresh checkout from source control

Comment: What version of ReSharper do you have?

Comment: JetBrains ReSharper 7.1.3 Full Edition
Build 7.1.3000.2254 on 2013-04-10T15:48:18

Comment: That is the last version. Did you change any options in ReSharper? And... can you compile your solution?

Comment: It compiles, and yes, of course, some inspection options are changed. But this cannot be changed, since R# thinks, this is a compile error

Comment: And if you try to create another wpf project. Do you still get the same problems? And you can try to delete "_ReSharper.*" folder located in each project folder.

Comment: Well, a fresh project is fine. Deleting the _Resharper folder won't help.

Comment: If closing your studio, deleting all _Resharper folders in the solution folder and then reopening the project didnt help you... then i dont know what to do next, sorry:( At least, you can create new project without any problems.

EDIT: Maybe... you can try to backup your MainWindow XAML and codebehind code, then delete the MainWindow files and then recreate it.

Comment: I had the same issue and can confirm that deleting _ReSharper works

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Remove `System.Windows` from your project references.

According to the docs [IComponentConnector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.icomponentconnector.aspx) was moved from `WindowsBase` to `System.Xaml`. I think that `System.Windows` may also be involved, but it isn't documented.

Comment: Wow. This does the trick. However, I'm using RelayCommand from MVVM Light, which is an implementation of System.Windows.ICommand. I changed all RelayCommands to Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.ActionCommands and now everything's fine.

Comment: Good to Know. I'll have to look at my project to see what we are referencing, but I didn't have a problem with the RelayCommand implementation. PS - Upvote it too please ;)

Comment: We're just referencing the version in System.dll http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx